Error "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled" OR "incorrect credential error"
When I'm performing scan-to-email from the printer encountering the below error
I get the same error "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled" or "incorrect credentials"
I have a personal email on @outlook.com @hotmail.com
And I have created app password.
SMTP Server : smtp-mail.outlook.com / smtp.office365.com
Port : 587 with TLS option, with server authentication enabled and provided outlook mail and app specific password.
Note : with the same printer FW and same configurations with regular password it is working fine on 16-sep-2024, but now it is not working, I have generated app specific password ,even with app password also facing the same error.
Please assist
solution for this problem

That is correct, outlook.com no longer allows basic auth.
